# What is the best way to implement app state restoration using MVVM with dependency injection?

Tags: ios, mvvm, dependency-injection

I have a project which uses MVVM architecture. Basically, the view model and its dependencies are constructed and assign to controller before the controller is displayed. I want to implement state restoration but the problem is that I can't encode the viewModel and it's dependency through `func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder)` method. What's the best way to dealing with this kind of scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: why can't you encode your viewModel?

Comment: ViewModel should be encodable, i.e. conforms to `NSCoding` or `Codable` for it to be encoded but a viewModel can have properties that can't be conform to these protocols.